# How do I GROUPBY with Coalesce in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I am aggregating Twitter data by hour and wish to get the hourly percentage pf tweets, and I can run:

```
SELECT CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) AS hr, 
COUNT(substr(created_at, 12, 2)) AS cnt , 
ROUND(100 * (count(substr(created_at, 12, 2)) / tot.total),2) AS 
cntpercent

FROM tweets0, (select count(*) AS total from tweets0 WHERE 
racist = true) tot WHERE racist = true

GROUP BY substr(created_at, 12, 2), tot.total
```

which gives:

```
hr  cnt cntpercent
0   153 3.79
1   144 3.56 ...
```

but then I realise I am not allowing for utc_offset so my SQL becomes horrendous:

```
SELECT CAST(coalesce(pmod(CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) 
+ (user.utc_offset/3600),24), CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT)) AS INT)
, COUNT(CAST(coalesce(pmod(CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) 
+ (user.utc_offset/3600),24), CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT)) AS INT)) 
AS cnt , 
ROUND(100 * ( CAST(coalesce(pmod(CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) 
+ (user.utc_offset/3600),24), CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT)) AS INT) 
             / tot.total),2) AS cntpercent

FROM tweets0, (select count(*) AS total from tweets0 WHERE racist = true) tot 
WHERE racist = true

GROUP BY CAST(coalesce(pmod(CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) 
+ (user.utc_offset/3600),24), CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT)) AS INT)
, tot.total
```

Problem is this gives a cumulative percentage:

```
_c0 cnt cntpercent
0   188 0.0
1   121 0.02
2   131 0.05
3   86  0.07 ...
```

I expect because of COALESCE in the GROUP by. Can anyone tell me how to fix this or do something else?

EDIT: AS per jarlh's recommendation, I now have a derived table version with the same problem:

```
SELECT hr_adj, COUNT(hr_adj) AS cnt, ROUND(100 * hour.hr_adj/ tot.total,2) AS cntpercent

FROM tweets0, (select count(*) AS total from tweets0 WHERE racist = true) tot, 
(SELECT CAST(coalesce(pmod(CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT) 
+ (user.utc_offset/3600),24), CAST(substr(created_at, 12, 2)  AS INT)) AS INT) 
AS hr_adj
 from tweets0 WHERE racist = true) hour WHERE racist = true

GROUP BY hour.hr_adj, tot.total
```

Comment: Do all the cast stuff in a derived table. Then GROUP BY etc its result.

Comment: Thanks can you give a brief example?